# Java code behaving unexpectedly

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a java solar system type simulator, and something is wrong with my physics and I cannot figure out why. I'm sure it's a simple one-liner mistake somewhere. What's happening, is one body will move and it looks like it will start orbit the other body, and then the body will fly off into space for no apparent reason. Here's the project on GitHub: https://github.com/Ronin11/FunWithGit/tree/dev

Here's the physics:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class physics {
private final static double G = 6.6738489E-11; //Newton's "Big" G
private final static double Multiplier = 10E9; //Gravity Equation Multiplier

private static double calculateGravity(Body m1, Body m2, boolean returnX){
    /***** Newton's universal law of gravitation with
            the distance formula substituted for r^2 ****/
    double force = ((G*m1.getMass()*m2.getMass())/
                     (StrictMath.pow((m2.getposx()-m1.getposx()),2) 
                       + StrictMath.pow((m2.getposy() - m1.getposy()), 2)));
    //System.out.println(force);
    double angle = StrictMath.atan((m2.getposy()-m1.getposy())/(m2.getposx()-m1.getposx()));
    //System.out.println(angle*180);
    if(returnX)
        force = force * StrictMath.cos(angle);
    else
        force = force * StrictMath.sin(angle);
    return force;
}

private static double calculateAcceleration(double Force, Body m){
    /** Force = Mass * Acceleration **/
    double Acc = Force/m.getMass();
    return Acc;
}

/** Change the velocity with the force calculations**/
private static void velChanges(Body b,ArrayList <Body> system){
    double xAccel = 0;
    double yAccel = 0;
    for (Body body: system){
        if(b != body){
            xAccel += calculateAcceleration(calculateGravity(b,body,true),b);
            yAccel += calculateAcceleration(calculateGravity(b,body,false),b);
        }
    }
    xAccel = Multiplier * xAccel; // Static Multipliers to
    yAccel = Multiplier * yAccel; //  make things play nicer
    b.setvelx(b.getvelx()+xAccel);
    b.setvely(b.getvely()+yAccel);
}

/** Change the position to the new position **/
private static void posChanges(Body b){
    b.setposx(b.getposx()+b.getvelx());
    b.setposy(b.getposy()+b.getvely());
}

/** Nice little method for GUI.java to call **/
public static void calculateChanges(ArrayList <Body> system){
    for (Body b: system) {
    velChanges(b,system);
    posChanges(b);
    }
}

}
```

And here's the Body class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
/**
 * 
 * @author Ronin
 * 
 *  The body class is a simple object used in the Gravity program.
 *  All bodies will have the six variables associated with them to
 *  run the simulation. Eventually the color variable will be 
 *  determined by the density of the body.
 *
 */

public class Body {
public Body(){
    mass = 100;
    size = 1;
    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;
    posX = 0;
    posY = 0;
    color = Color.white;
}

public Body(int mass, int size, Color color, double velX, double velY, double posX, double posY){
    this.mass = mass;
    this.size = size;
    this.color = color;
    this.velX = velX;
    this.velY = velY;
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;

}
//Getters
public int getMass(){return mass;}
public int getSize(){return size;}
public double getvelx(){return velX;}
public double getvely(){return velY;}
public double getposx(){return posX+velX;}
public double getposy(){return posY+velY;}
public Color getColor(){return color;}
//Setters
public void setMass(int m){mass = m;}
public void setSize(int s){size = s;}
public void setvelx(double v){velX = v;}
public void setvely(double v){velY = v;}
public void setposx(double p){posX = p;}
public void setposy(double p){posY = p;}
public void setColor(Color c){color = c;}

//Member Variables
private Color color;
private int mass;
private int size;
private double velX;
private double velY;
private double posX;
private double posY;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: so what's the problem?...

Comment: @Sionnach733 why don't you read what he wrote at the top

Comment: I edited the post after Sionnach's comment. Sorry!

Comment: A typical problem with gravity simulations is failing to account for the fact that in the real universe, there are no 'point' masses (if you discount black holes).  I.E. A small object that passes very close to an Earth mass object but passing so close that it would (in reality) be 'below ground level' might get a phenomenal gravity boost from Earth, thereby flinging it clear out of the solar system.  In reality, it would crash into the Earth surface, but the simulation does not take that into account.

Comment: Tip: if you can afford to move to Java 8 you have annotations for unit measurements, that can prevent many unexpected behaviors.

Comment: @user1803551 What are you referring to?

Comment: Is it possible that the body flying away has simply been a subjected to gravitational slingshot effect?  Try lowering it's speed, or moving slightly away from the nearest (in terms of mass * distance) body to see.

Comment: I fixed it by adding a -1 multiplier to the forces in the 1st and 3rd quadrant (if the mass was above and to the right of the other mass or if the mass was below and to the left of the other mass). And things started to act normal after that.

Comment: @Boann To something like [this](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#units-checker).